# Spring REST controller with different functions

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring `@RestController` for manipulating my Users and I want to have several functions:

- /users : GET (returns all users)
- /users/:id : GET (returns a user with given ID, default id=1)
- /users : POST (inserts a user)
- /users/:id : DELETE (deletes a user with given ID)

I started working on it but I'm not sure how to manage the "overlapping" URIs for the same method (e.g. first two cases). Here's what I came with so far:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return UserDAO.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(@RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "1") int id) {
        return UserDAO.getById(id);
    }
}
```

This won't work due to "ambiguous mapping" and it's pretty clear to me, but I don't know what to do. Should I change one of the URIs or there is some other way?

Edit: 
I've also tried changing the second method to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    return UserDAO.getById(id);
}
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to map the desired `/users/:id `, you should define a `@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)` and capture that `{id}` with a `@PathVariable int id`.

Comment: @AliDehghani look at my edit... it still doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by `Still doesn't work..`? If getting any exception, post the full stacktrace...

Comment: @AliDehghani  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'candidateController' method 
public java.util.List<model.Candidate> controller.CandidateController.getAllCandidates()
to {[/candidates],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'candidateController' bean method
public model.Candidate controller.CandidateController.getUser(int) mapped.`

Comment: CandidateController, UserController, same logic but different name

Comment: My mistake... I have changed one file but the error was in another one. I'm a moron :). @AliDehghani if you want to post an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUser(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int id)
```

Would map to the `/users?id=42` not the desired `/users/42`. If you want to create a mapping for `/users/:id` endpoint, use the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
    return UserDAO.getById(id);
}
```

Also, as of Spring Framework 4.3, you can use [new meta annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-composed) to handle `GET`, `POST`, etc. methods:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return UserDAO.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        return UserDAO.getById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sura2k Then [this](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-composed) may sound interesting, too.